# RSelenium and Docker on EC2

Tags: r, docker, amazon-ec2, rselenium

My final goal is to be able to use [rselenium](/questions/tagged/rselenium) through [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) my EC2 instance (AWS).

For that, I read that it is recommeneded to use and install a docker on a virtual machine. So I followed all the steps given by John D Harrison here:
https://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker

And everything went fine except at the end when I enter in `RStudio` on my `EC2` instance.
Because when I try to connect to the remote server I get the below error:

`library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L)
remDr$open()`

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBA26.png) "Connecting to remote server" Error in checkError(res) : 
>   Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Timeout was reached:
>   Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

I followed the exact steps given in the tutorial so I really don't know what is wrong.

Any help much appreciated !

M.

EDIT1:
Please find below screenshots of what I have so far:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: EDIT 5: Security Groups Port within EC2]

My EC2 instance I use is the following:
[image: My EC2 instance I use is the following:]

Comment: Have you opened port 4445 on the virtual machine? Have you also started the Docker container so that it exposes this port?

Comment: Yes I did, I will edit my post to give more details.

Comment: What is the IP address of the machine where the docker container is running?

Comment: I edited my post: the docker machine ip is 192.168.99.100

Comment: And is there a firewall in the way that is causing port 4445 to be closed?

Comment: would it be within AWS? I don't use any firewall on my side

Comment: Yes, AWS implements a firewall and you have to explicitly open the ports you want. Search for Security Groups

Comment: I added Security Group settings for port 4445 (see my edit) but I still have the same issue when I do: _remDr$open()_
#> [1] "Connecting to remote server"
#> Error in checkError(res): Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused

Comment: I was able to make it work. I'll put the steps in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me.

Create an EC2 Ubuntu instance with Docker installed. I didn't use Windows.

Run the selenium docker image on the EC2 instance as follows

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0
```

Ensure port 4445 is open from the IP address where you are running R by creating the appropriate entry in the security group.

On my desktop machine that can see the EC2 instance, use this R code to connect...

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "ec2-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com", port = 4445L)
remDr$open()

#[1] "Connecting to remote server"
#$applicationCacheEnabled
#[1] TRUE

#$rotatable
#[1] FALSE

#$handlesAlerts
#[1] TRUE
#...
```

Note the address of the EC2 instance is "ec2...". This address is available from the AWS console and is the public DNS name of the instance. If you happen to be running R on another AWS machine, then you would probably need to use the private DNS address.

[Edited to add instructions for running Rstudio in the cloud]

Find the IP address of the Selenium container. One way is to log into it as follows

```
docker exec -it <nameofthecontainer> bash
hostname -i
exit
```

To run Rstudio on the same EC2 machine as Selenium, one option is to use Docker. A good image is `rocker/rstudio`.

Do the following.

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=<password> --name rstudio rocker/rstudio
```

Make sure port 8787 is open to you from where you want to access Rstudio. Add entries in the security group for the instance to do this.

To install RSelenium in the Rstudio docker container, do the following.

```
docker exec rstudio bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libxml2-dev
exit
```

Find the URL of the Rstudio GUI - it will be something like this

```
http://ec2-xxx:8787
```

The username is rstudio and the password is whatever you specified when you started the container.

Install the RSelenium package from Rstudio.

```
install.packages("RSelenium")
```

Finally run the R code to access the Selenium instance.

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "IP address of the Selenium container", port = 4445L)
remDr$open()
```

Comment: I modified the remoteServerAddr with the DNS public of my EC2 but I still received that httr call error. You say: "Create an EC2 Ubuntu instance with Docker installed. I didn't use Windows." ==> I edited my post to show you the instance I am using, it's Linux and not Windows, should I switch to the 4th one Ubuntu? That would mean I need to install RStudio on that new instance, which I will if needed.

Comment: New information: you have Docker and Rstudio on the same EC2 instance. Can I suggest you run Rstudio on a desktop machine to see if you can recreate what I did?

Comment: I updated with instructions to run everything in the same machine using a docker Rstudio. It works for me.

Comment: `docker exec rstudio bash` may need to be `docker exec -i -t rstudio /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @awchisholm ! As you explaied, I needed to install docker on my EC2 instance and not on my local machine. Problem solved!