# scheduling scraping/downloading of file from site via RStudio Server on EC2 and RSelenium (?)

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, web-scraping, cron, rselenium

I would like to schedule daily downloads of a file (which is daily updated) from a [website](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/report/) (download button at the very end of the page). So far I figured out that one possible avenue is to set up an EC2 instance on Amazon WS which runs RStudio Server (see e.g. [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-run-rstudio-on-aws-in-under-3-minutes-for-free-65f8d0b6ccda)). Here the script could be triggered by e.g. the `cronR` package.

I manage to download the file on my local machine with the RSelenium package (below the code).

```
library(RSelenium)

#open server
rd <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 4444L)

#open browser
ffd <- rd$client

#navigate to target url
url <- 'https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/report/'
ffd$navigate(url)

css_selector <- "._7vio"
download_btn <- ffd$findElement(using = "css selector", css_selector)
download_btn$clickElement()
```

However, running RSelenium in an AWS instance seems (at least for me) to be a rather intimidating task which I haven't yet figured out (installing a docker image with RSelenium on the EC2..e.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916609/rselenium-and-docker-on-ec2) or [here](https://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker)).

Hence I was wondering whether there isn't an easier way which would allow me to run a simple script in RStudio Server without the need for RSelenium. The challenge I am facing is how to trigger a click on the download button without RSelenium (and Docker etc)? I gather that there might be 'some way' to get the file via a POST request. The developer tools reveal that the click on the download button trigger a POST/GET command, but I am here only poking and not really sure how to proceed.

PS: I know that there is also an facebook API, but the information provided is not identical to the info in the daily reports.